# In Unity, switching mesh on skinnedMeshRenderer works in editor but not in build

Tags: unity, mesh, bug

I got this very annoying bug, since it's only related to build and I'm wondering why that bug does not appear in editor.
I'm trying to switch the mesh that SkinnedMeshRenderer displays with another similar one, it works as expected in editor.
Here's a short video of the working version in editor.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xm1Fw9bgCRc

When trying to do the same thing on Build, I get this weird bug where the skinnedMeshRenderer seems to stop working when switching mesh.

Instead of having the mesh following properly the character, it just hang above it.
See the picture below :
[image: bug cloth]

When building, I get a few warning and exceptions, I don't know if it's related and if it is, I don't know how to solve those.  :
[image: warnings]

Comment: Share error messages as text (searchable, screen-readable, translatable, copy-paste-able), not as images.

Comment: The warnings and errors seem to tell you in no uncertain terms "This material does not work on this build target". Have you tried using a different material to see if it behaves better?

Answer (score 0):

I think the target device can't handle the shader that you are using.
Try use a different material with the unity default shader and see if this bug still occurs